# Run custom Speculator in Hadoop 2.6.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am programming my custom speculator, I reviewed documentation and by default is "`DefaultSpeculator.java`" and is set in  class `"MRAppMaster.java" (function createSpeculator())` in core of Hadoop. I want to know if you can update/change speculator in runtime when executing my job, because i need to test between about 5 speculators.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speculative execution can be turned on and off for map tasks and reduce tasks on a cluster-wide basis or on a per-job basis.

The speculator is instantiated in `MRAppMaster` (Map-Reduce Application Master). As you mentioned in your question, following is the piece of code in `MRAppMaster::serviceInit()` function, which instantiates the speculator:

```
if (conf.getBoolean(MRJobConfig.MAP_SPECULATIVE, false)
      || conf.getBoolean(MRJobConfig.REDUCE_SPECULATIVE, false)) {
    //optional service to speculate on task attempts' progress
    speculator = createSpeculator(conf, context);
    addIfService(speculator);
}
```

It checks the `JobConfig`, to see if speculative execution is turned on for either Map or Reduce tasks and then creates the speculator.

Since the speculator is created inside the `MRAppMaster`, you can enable your custom speculator for each job.

Following are the speculative execution properties:

- **mapreduce.map.speculative**: Enable speculative execution for map tasks
- **mapreduce.reduce.speculative**: Enable speculative execution for reduce 
  tasks
- **yarn.app.mapreduce.am.job.speculator.class**: Speculator class
- **yarn.app.mapreduce.am.job.task.estimator.class**: Estimator class. This is used by speculator for estimating the run time of a task.